# How do I set environment variable for all users even when doing sudo su?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, su

I created a file named `x.sh` in the directory `/etc/profile.d/` so it should be accessible to all users. I expected when I change the current user in terminal (of logged-in user) using command `sudo su other_user`, those variable that I set in `x.sh` file should be accessible but they not. How can I set variables to be accessible as I desired?

Comment: Just an additional note: never use ``sudo su``. This is an abuse of the su command, just to get a shell. The correct way is to use ``sudo -s`` (shell with your current environment) or ``sudo -i`` (login shell). This avoids running a useless ``su`` command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/etc/profile` (and hence `/etc/profile.d`) is read for login shells. `sudo su other_user` does not run a login shell. It is a bad practice, it leaves the environment [contaminated with variables from the original user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/35342/260978). You should do either of these commands instead:

```
sudo -iu other_user
sudo su - other_user
```

Both of these load `/etc/profile` because they start login shells, and both start with relatively clean environments.

Ideally, though, the variables should be set in `/etc/environment` if possible. That file *should* be read by `su`, so variables there would be available irrespective of whether a login shell is started. However, that file doesn't support shell syntax, so if you need complex shell code to set your variables, you can't use it.

Comment: Just the second command `sudo su - other_user` worked, pls edit.

Comment: @soheil `sudo -i other_user` didn't work?

Comment: no, it didn't work `the command not found`, maybe you mean `sudo su -l other_user`

Comment: @soheil Command not found? What exactly did you run? If you can do `sudo su`, the `sudo` command exists and is clearly runnable by you. O.o

Comment: the output of the command `sudo -i other_user` is `-bash: other_user: command not found`

Comment: @soheil Oh, I see. My apologies. I forgot the `-u` option. It should be `sudo -iu other_user`. Edited the post now.

Answer (score 2):

Following [How to permanently set environmental variables · U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/117470/246819) `bash` will load

```
/etc/profile
```

so that's the right place to add variables effective for all users.

Comment: I tried that but It was not desirable. I login using user A and myVariable are accessible but when I change user to user B  through terminal using command `sudo su B`, myVariables for user B are not accssible!